# User enters letter then button computes position from a string using VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using `indexOf` but I cannot figure out where I made a mistake as the output gives a `-1`.

I realise I can copy the whole statement paragraph into the last line of the output but I was hoping it could pull it straight from the label.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
    Dim statement As String
    Dim letter As String
    statement = CStr(lblStatement.Text)
    letter = CStr(txtLetter.Text)
    txtOutput.Text = CStr(lblStatement.Text).IndexOf("letter")
    'txtOutput.Text = letter.ToUpper & " first occurs in position " & statement.IndexOf(statement) & "."
  End Sub
End Class
```

Here is a picture of the form:

[image]

Update: Thanks to @ADyson and @Slugsie for taking the time to respond to my call for help. As @Slugsie noted it was indeed down to the lower case in my screenshot. I am now researching how to make it work without being case-sensitive.

Final code 
`Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
txtOutput.Text = lblStatement.Text.IndexOf((txtLetter.Text).ToUpper)
End Sub
End Class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.IndexOf("letter")
```

is looking for the literal text `letter` within the data the user enters in the text. in VB.NET (and most other programming languages), anything enclosed within quote marks is treated as a fixed string of text, to be interpreted as-is rather than processed or treated as program code.

To make it look for the contents of the `letter` variable instead (which looks like what you were intending) simply remove the quote marks:

```
.IndexOf(letter)
```

---

As an aside, your whole code could be much reduced - primarily the use of `CStr` is unnecessary, because the `Text` properties of the textbox and label already return a string - meaning you don't need to use `CStr` convert it - and also because you're not making use of all the variables you declared either.

You could re-write your whole sample much more succinctly as:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
    txtOutput.Text = lblStatement.Text.IndexOf(txtLetter.Text)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Also worth noting that from the sample picture, it would still return -1 as lower case 'b' does not appear in the upper case 'THE QUICK BROWN...'(etc).

Comment: I am very grateful, you were right, it is down to the lower case 'b', I wonder if there is a way to make it not be case sensitive.

Comment: @RelebogileChiloane Yes there is. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-5.0#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_StringComparison_ and then study the StringComparison options.